# Easiest/cheapest way to light a redstone lamp when mobs fall through tunnel onto hoppers

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am playing an MCPE hermit chunk map. There is 1x 16x16 chunk for me to work with, and so far no access to the nether. I have limited supplies, so the cheaper the better. Also, since I do not currently have access to the nether, comparators are out.

I have a mob grinder with a 2x2 hole down the middle. The mobs fall down this hole onto half slabs, die, and their items are collected by hoppers underneath the slabs. I am trying to find a way to visually tell when mobs fall through. I can either find a way to detect them falling in the hole, or their items being picked up. Either would be fine with me.

I would prefer to have a redstone lamp light up because I feel this is the easiest to see form a distance. I am currently on MCPE 14.2 (Windows 10 version, but basically same thing in this case)

Comment: You don't light a redstone block.

Comment: Yes @Peanut, I realized when I read your response that I meant a redstone lamp. I will edit my text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use comparators there's no way to detect when the hopper picks up an item.

What I'd recommend doing is placing a tripwire inside the hole, so it triggers when the mobs fall through it. Then you can simply hook it up to anything you like.

Here's an example:[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1):

To detect if an item has been collected by a hopper, you can simply place a comparator adjacent to it, with the two-torch side touching the hopper.
[image]

The repeater then amplifies the signal so it does not matter how many items are in the hopper. Once we add an item...

[image]

We now know that there is an item in the hopper.

Comment: Note: You can also attach hoppers to chests and double chests so there is more space in the container.